# Angular: attach $viewContentLoaded to manually bootstraped app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, rootscope

i have a angular module that i bootstrap manually.i am trying to get its `$rootScope` to attach a event listener for `$viewContentLoaded`.

here is my code :

```
angular.bootstrap(el, [appname]);
//////////////////////////// Fixing links
console.log('patching');
var $rootScope = angular.injector([appname]).get('$rootScope');
console.log($rootScope);// Scope { $id=139,  $root=Scope,  $$destroyed=false,  more...}
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('$viewContentLoaded');
});
```

I am getting a scope `$id=139` and the event is not firing when it should.

If i try to get the `$rootScope` inside my modules main controlelr i get :

```
console.log('myController',$rootScope);
Scope { $id=120,  $$childTail=Scope,  $$childHead=Scope,  more...}
```

I get a `$rootScope` with id 120???

and If i attach the event to the controller inside the module the event handler works as it should.

So what am i doing wrong?
How can i get the correct `rootScope` of a module outside of its controller?

I should mention that i have a multiple app environment. I have a main module that load and bootstraps other modules and i am trying to know when this other modules viewContent has finished loading with out adding the code to every each one of the manually....

Note: 
  I can get the `$rootScope` like this :

```
var $rootScope = angular.element(el).scope().$root;
```

But this doesn't work when `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok , here is what i ended up with if any one interested :

```
(function (angular) {

    var origMethod = angular.module;

    angular.module = function (name, reqs, configFn) {
        var module = origMethod(name, reqs, configFn);

        module.run(function ($rootScope) {
            //////////////////////////// Fixing links
            $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                ___fixLinks($('[ng-view],ng-view,.ng-view','[ngg-app="' + name + '"]'));
            });
        });

        return module;
    };

})(angular);
```